# Fractional number of particles in the universe?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, cosmology, universe, elementary-particles

Is it possible, that the metagalaxy contains a fractional (non whole) number of particles or fractional number of a particular kind of particles (such as electrons)?

Sorry, if my question is stupid, my knowledge of QM is limited by popular science.

Comment: The number operator has only integer eigenvalues. OTOH, the notion of "particle" is not well defined on the galactic scale because the curvature could vary appreciably at that scale.

Comment: First time seeing OTOH....on the other hand, just to save some people time.

Comment: Not quite in the same vein, but some QCD theorists find it useful to treat the number of strong-force colors $n_c$ as a parameter and take limits on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a particle either "is" or "isn't", then its count is either 1 or 0. Even in quantum mechanics it's not possible that half a particle exists. It *is* possible to detect it with 50% probability, but if you set about counting all the particles one at a time, you necessarily end up with an integer answer.